# How to handle loop and promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, es6-promise

I use Promised inside a loop.

I tried to do a loop but the iterator is (of course) changing with the loop.

```
let fctPromise = (i) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true + "//" + i)
        }, parseInt(i) * 1000)
    });
}

var arr = [5, 3, 4, 2, 1];

for (var i of arr) {
    fctPromise(i).then(value => console.log(value, "////", i))
}
```

Loop is working correctly, it goes through the array. But `i` is changing Should I change the way I am approching it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let fctPromise = (i) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true + "//" + i)
        }, parseInt(i) * 1000)
    });
}

var arr = [5, 3, 4, 2, 1];

for (let i of arr) {
    fctPromise(i).then(value => console.log(value, "////", i))
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2fdk6err/1/

instead of using

> var i of arr

use

> let i of arr

Comment: Let is the new var !!

Comment: let fixs a lot of problems that var has :D

Answer (score 1):

So I just change this part of code :

```
 for (var lang of language)
```

to

```
   for (let lang of language)
```

**let is the new var !**

Answer (score 0):

The lang variable after promise resolves is changes. So I think you should keep lang variable with resolve of promise.

```
let iterateOnJson = (jsonObj, originLanguage, TargetLanguage) => {
    var promiseAll = [];
    let jsonObjClone = merge.mergeDeep({}, jsonObj);
    let iterateInner = (jsonObj) => {
        for (let item in jsonObj) {
            if (typeof(jsonObj[item]) == "string") {
                let promise = translateIt(jsonObj[item], originLanguage, TargetLanguage).then(translatedWord => jsonObj[item] = JSON.parse(translatedWord).translationText);
                promiseAll.push(promise);
            } else {
                iterateInner(jsonObj[item])
            }
        }

    }
    iterateInner(jsonObjClone);
    return Promise.all(promiseAll).then(data => {
        return { jsonObjClone: jsonObjClone,
                 lang: TargetLanguage };
    });
}


//HERE IS THE LOOP
for (var lang of language) {
    console.log(lang);
    iterateOnJson(translateFile, "fr", lang).then(value => {
        let fileTitle = value.lang;
        fs.writeFile("mypath/" + fileTitle + i + ".json", JSON.stringify(value.jsonObjClone),
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("The file was saved!", value.lang);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: I modified my question to make it easier to understand

Comment: Yup, I see. Your answer is totally better then mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, try to use Promise.all() :

```
let fctPromise = (i) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true + "//" + i)
        }, parseInt(i) * 1000)
    });
}

var arr = [5, 3, 4, 2, 1];

Promise.all(arr.map(i=>{
    return fctPromise(i).then(value => console.log(value, "////", i))
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

please do not use `var` and use `const` instead like this

```
for (const i of arr) {...}
```

```js
let fctPromise = (i) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true + "//" + i)
        }, parseInt(i) * 1000)
    });
}

var arr = [5, 3, 4, 2, 1];

for (const i of arr) {
    fctPromise(i).then(value => console.log(value, "////", i))
}

/* print 
true//1 //// 1
true//2 //// 2
true//3 //// 3
true//4 //// 4
true//5 //// 5
*/
```